# Ember-data strange behavior with many-to-many relationships

Tags: ember.js, many-to-many, ember-data

I'm trying to implement a friending system in Ember, which is a many-to-many relationship.  My models are:

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend
  name: DS.attr('string')
  friendships: DS.hasMany('friendship', { inverse: 'user' })

App.Friendship = DS.Model.extend
  user: DS.belongsTo('user')
  friend: DS.belongsTo('user')
```

In my User controller, I have an `addFriend` action that looks roughly like this (I have `currentUser` defined from elsewhere):

```
App.UserController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
  actions:
    addFriend: ->
      friendship = @get('store').createRecord('friendship', 
        user: @get('currentUser')
        friend: @get('model')
      )
      @get('currentUser.friendships').pushObject(friendship)
```

From debug statements, it seems like the `friendship` record is being pushed into the `friendships` array of **BOTH** `currentUser` and the user represented by `model`.  I don't want this to happen, because for a bidirectional friending system, the `model.friendship` array should contain the inverse of `friendship` i.e. with user and friend swapped.  Of course it would be nice if Ember had a way to do this automatically, but I'm perfectly happy to do it manually as well.

For now, why is the `pushObject` method pushing the same `friendship` record into both user records?  I guess it might have something to do with the way inverses are defined in the models.  I tried changing to `inverse: null` but that did not solve the problem.  What is happening under the hood with ember-data that is causing this behavior?  Or is there a bug in my code somewhere that I have not seen?  Any way to get rid of this behavior would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!  It turns out I needed

```
App.Friendship = DS.Model.extend
  user: DS.belongsTo('user')
  friend: DS.belongsTo('user', { inverse: null })
```

I was intuitively right that the answer had something to do with inverses, but I didn't put the `inverse: null` in the correct place at first!